# Show (continuously) summary in a for next cycle

Tags: for-loop, regression, lm, summary

I have the following code, and I want to show the results of each regression (summary) continuously at each for next cycle

```
data("popular")
variabile<-names(popular)

for(i in 1:4) {
    assign(paste0("lm", i), lm(paste0(variabile[i], "~ texp"), data=popular))
    summary(lm(i))
}
```

However, summary doesn't work in that way, but I wasn't able to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple answer:

```
data("popular")
variabile<-names(popular)

for(i in 1:4) {
assign(paste0("lm", i), lm(paste0(variabile[i], "~ texp"), data=popular))
print(summary(get(paste0("lm", i))))
}
```